# $$LAST_EXTRACT_DATE not in parameter file in informatica mapping - when run through DAC

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have created a new mapping in Informatica and I defined a mapping parameter $$LAST_EXTRACT_DATE (this is already defined in DAC(as it is working for out of box mappings)). However, When DAC is executing, this variable is not getting its values in parameter file of mapping. Other mappings are working fine. It's just this mapping which has an issue. I am trying to make this mapping to run in incremental.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

Yogesh,

I assumed that your mapping run with no issue and parameter $$LAST_EXTRACT_DATE are being replaced with a correct date through the DAC. You don't parameter file if you using DAC to run mapping. A parameter file is needed when you start the task from Informatica.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the same file is used while running through DAC, as it's possible to run workflows in two ways:

- just starting a workflow will make it read parameter file specified in the properties
- starting workflow with indicated parameter file will make it read the given file INSTEAD OF the one specified in the properties.